# select option is not visible in Datatable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, bootstrap-selectpicker

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Zlfrtip',
    colReorder: true,
    scrollY:        300,
    deferRender: true,
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scroller: false,
    deferRender: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
    ordering: false,
    info: false,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "Item",
        "width": "200px"
    }, ],
    "colResize": {
        "tableWidthFixed": false
    }
});
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      size: 12,
      dropupAuto: false
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover order-column item_data" id="example" style="table-layout: fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
       <select class="form-control selectpicker">
          <option>Example 1</option>
          <option>Example 2</option>
          <option>Example 3</option>
          <option>Example 4</option>
          <option>Example 5</option>
       </select>
           </td>
       </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone look this code and please tell me why selectpicker showing option inside the table. How can I show option on table, I tried z-index but that was not worked. Thanks in advance. It is working perfectly when I remove

> scrollCollapse: true

For some reason I cant remove this. Anyone have solution without removing it?

Answer (score 0):

The class call `dataTables_scrollBody` have a `overflow: auto;`
You have to select this in `none`.

```
.dataTables_scrollBody{
  overflow:none
}
```

Comment: It will impact scrollCollapse: true behavior?

Comment: If I have understand well your needs yes will work, try this on `inspector web` in your example code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the option `{"container": "body"}` for `selectpicker`. Here's a snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Zlfrtip',
    colReorder: true,
    scrollY:        300,
    deferRender: true,
    scrollX:        true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    scroller: false,
    deferRender: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    searching: false,
    paging: false,
    ordering: false,
    info: false,
    "columns": [{
        "data": "Item",
        "width": "200px"
    }, ],
    "colResize": {
        "tableWidthFixed": false
    }
});
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
      size: 12,
      dropupAuto: false,
      container: 'body'
  });
})
```

```html
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover order-column item_data" id="example" style="table-layout: fixed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
       <select class="form-control selectpicker">
          <option>Example 1</option>
          <option>Example 2</option>
          <option>Example 3</option>
          <option>Example 4</option>
          <option>Example 5</option>
       </select>
           </td>
       </tr> 
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the **doc** for the same: [BS Selectpicker's container option](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#container)